# Animations in c++, interpolating keyframes with rotation matrices

Tags: c++, animation, 3d, rotation

In my application, i have a 3D-Model, where i can rotate, scale, translate by setting the values manually..i can also extract the rotation at a given point. So i can store keyframes now, with the 4x4 matrix for each joint.

However, now i want to animate between those frames. 
What i want :
interpolate from frame 1 to frame 2 within X seconds. How can i implement this in C++??
I found something like http://www-scf.usc.edu/~amahajan/mocap/mocap4.html ...but i have no clue how to write this in c++

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved this...the Eigen library has already a Quaternion1.slerp(Quaternion2, float T) function. If you dont know what SLERP is: slerp interpolates between one Quaternion and another one, the float T can be considered as the increment, how far much it should interpolate. For example: if you give slerp a unit quaternion,  a Y 90° quaternion, and the float T a "0.5" value, the outcome is a Quaternion with Y 45°. For detailed information about slerp you should google it, it is well known.

If you use Eigen, you can simply make Quaternions out of the rotation matrices :

```
Matrix3f m;
Quaternion<float> q1=m.toRotationMatrix();
```

With this i simply created a loop that goes from 0.01 to 1.00 with increment 0.01. 
You should do this work in another thread:

```
    for(double i=0.0;i<1.0;i=i+0.01)
    {
        //let this thread sleep for 10 millisec, this gives us a 100hertz rate
        //with this, the whole animation is over in 1 second
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(10));
        //q1= first frame, q2 = second frame
        Quaternion<float> q3(q1.slerp(i,q2));
        //now apply the quaternion
        // for each "bone", or node you need to apply a SLERPed quaternion
        m_node->setRotation(q3.toRotationMatrix());
    }
```